# OpenGL equivalent of vulkan's VK_KHR_display

Tags: opengl, vulkan

Is there (possibly via vendor specific extensions) an equivalent to vulkan's VK_KHR_display in OpenGL that would allow to present directly to the display device, bypassing any potential window manager?

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL does not directly deal with any form of display tech. That's the responsibility of [EGL](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/)/GLX/WGL or whatever other interface you use to create your GL context. So any such feature would come from one of those interfaces, not OpenGL itself.

It should be noted however that presenting to the display directly is not exactly a common feature. VK_KHR_display is only [available on Linux-based implementations](http://vulkan.gpuinfo.org/listreports.php?instanceextension=VK_KHR_display). So you should look towards GLX or EGL.

Comment: It should be pointed out, that on Linux with GPUs that are supported by DRM+KMS+DRI you can create a Xorg-less direct to display OpenGL context quite easily Google for `kmscube`. In display server environments there DRM leasing: https://keithp.com/blogs/DRM-lease/ – and it should not come as a surprise that VK_KHR_display is built upon those low level APIs.